# Android referral not firing the BroadCast Receiver

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play

I wrote an app that has the following BroadcastReceiver :

```
<receiver
            android:exported="true"
            android:name="com.package.InstallReferrerReceiver" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

The intent fires fine when I am using

```
am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER
        -n com.example.gatestapp/com.google.analytics.tracking.android.CampaignTrackingReceiver
        --es  "referrer" "utm_source=testSource&utm_medium=testMedium&utm_term=testTerm&utm_content=testContent&utm_campaign=testCampaign"
```

But, on uploading this app as a Beta version, it doesnt seem to fire (in the receiver,it should contact a webservice).

I made the link and sent it to people in messages.They opened the referral links in the browser.

What could the problem be ? Is it that it wont work for Beta? or , is there any 'correct' way of downloading from the play store via play ?

Comment: Are you sure that you haven't another receiver which INSTALL_REFERRER action in your manifest? Sometimes ads requested this.

Comment: in the whole app, i have just one receiver.

Comment: but suppose i had another, why would this receiver not be fired ?

Comment: Only one receiver can intercept INSTALL_REFERRER action

Comment: oh, okay. but anyway, i have only one

Comment: also, i tested this method on devices with version > 4.1. is it supported by these versions?